# OSMdroid tiles not loading due to java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am currently developing an Android application and I need to import and use OpenStreetMap. For this reason I use the osmdroid library 6.0.1 . Unfortunately, when I start the application, the tiles are not loading due to java.net.UnknownHostException. 
That's what I get as a result on both - the emulator and on my smart phone when I run the application:
[Emulator - Application Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EP9o6.png)

Here is the exception that repeatedly comes when I move the map or zoom in and out.

```
W/OsmDroid: UnknownHostException downloading MapTile: /0/0/0 : java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "a.tile.openstreetmap.org": No address associated with hostname
I/OsmDroid: Tile loader can't continue: /0/0/0
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
W/OsmDroid: UnknownHostException downloading MapTile: /0/0/0 : java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "b.tile.openstreetmap.org": No address associated with hostname
I/OsmDroid: Tile loader can't continue: /0/0/0
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
```

This is the **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MapActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

This is my **activity_map.xml**:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<org.osmdroid.views.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    /></LinearLayout>
```

And this is the **MapActivity.java**:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import org.osmdroid.api.IMapController;
import org.osmdroid.config.Configuration;
import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.TileSourceFactory;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;

public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
MapView map = null;
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
    Configuration.getInstance().load(ctx, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx));
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
    IMapController mapController = map.getController();
    GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(48.8583, 2.2944);
    mapController.setCenter(startPoint);
}
}
```

Do you have any clues what the problem may be?

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**

The code suddenly worked. I haven't changed anything. I just started the application one day and all the tiles loaded and appeared. I guess the problem was with the network or maybe the developers fixed a bug in osmdroid.

Comment: I think that your code is correct. The `UknownHostException` means, that the device is unable to resolve IP for domain name `a.tile.openstreetmap.org` etc. This would mean that either your internet connection doesn't work or you have some problem with DNS or your application doesn't have a network permission. I see network permission in your manifest, so it would be one of the first two. Check airplane mode, wifi connection, try to restart emulator, try to acces https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org from browser.

Comment: @JosefAdamcik Thank you very much for the answer. I have checked all the things you listed - wifi is on, airplane mode is off and I have also tried it on my smart phone, but still not working.  a.tile.openstreetmap.org works from my browser. What could the problem with the DNS be? And could the problem be connected with the Android SDK Version?

Comment: One other thing to check in the osmdroid code (not yours) - is it trying to fetch tiles from http or https?  http will no longer work.

Comment: To resolve this I had to close the Virtual Android Device and Cold Boot it again